# Block Struts action externally but make it accessible internally?

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I'm using struts 2 & I've a page which shows info of my website version via below URL:

```
https://www.mysite.com/info
```

Is there a way to block this /info page to public externally & make it accessible only within my office internal network?

If so, how to achieve it?

Note: I'm using Tomcat server.

Thanks!

Comment: how about blocking through apache httpd.conf or .htaccess

Comment: I'm using tomcat server ...How do I do it with tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tomcat there is a filter known as R`emote Address Filter` as per the doc

> The Remote Address Filter allows you to compare the IP address of the client that submitted this request against one or more regular expressions, and either allow the request to continue or refuse to process the request from this client. A Remote Address Filter can be associated with any Catalina container (Engine, Host, or Context), and must accept any request presented to this container for processing before it will be passed on.
>
> The syntax for regular expressions is different than that for 'standard' wildcard matching. Tomcat uses the java.util.regex package. Please consult the Java documentation for details of the expressions supported.

For more information you read tomcat documents [Remote_Address_Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Address_Filter)